# how to remove a #cdata-section in php xml dom?

Tags: php, xml

I want to parse xml files, The best way I found is to use DOMDocument() class so far.
but i found a problem with #cdata-section

sample xml string:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://www.blablal.id/news/sitemap.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>
      <![CDATA[ 2022-02-02T12:21:02+07:00 ]]>
    </lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

I use function dom2array.

```
 <?php
function xml_to_array($root)
{
        $result = array();

        if ($root->hasAttributes()) {
                $attrs = $root->attributes;
                foreach ($attrs as $attr) {
                        $result['@attributes'][$attr->name] = $attr->value;
                }
        }

        if ($root->hasChildNodes()) {
                $children = $root->childNodes;
                if ($children->length == 1) {
                        $child = $children->item(0);
                        if (in_array($child->nodeType,[XML_TEXT_NODE,XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE])) {
                                $result['_value'] = $child->nodeValue;
                                return count($result) == 1
                                        ? $result['_value']
                                        : $result;
                        }
                }
                $groups = array();
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                        if($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE && empty(trim($child->nodeValue))) continue;
                        if (!isset($result[$child->nodeName])) {
                                $result[$child->nodeName] = xml_to_array($child);
                        } else {
                                if (!isset($groups[$child->nodeName])) {
                                        $result[$child->nodeName] = array($result[$child->nodeName]);
                                        $groups[$child->nodeName] = 1;
                                }
                                $result[$child->nodeName][] = xml_to_array($child);
                        }
                }
        }

        return $result;
}

$xml = file_get_contents("sitemap.xml");
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadXML($xml);
$array = xml_to_array($document);
var_dump($array);
```

Is there any way to parse all xml elements and sent them to an array?

output array:

```
array(1) {
  ["sitemapindex"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["sitemap"]=>
    array(92) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["loc"]=>
        string(37) "https://www.blablal.id/news/sitemap.xml"
        ["lastmod"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["#cdata-section"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

how to get a lastmod value? like this 2022-02-02T12:21:02+07:00

Comment: The problem is in the recursive `$result[$child->nodeName] = xml_to_array($child);` calls. `if ($root->hasChildNodes())` won't be true for CDATA nodes, so these calls will only return an empty array. You need to check the node type in the places where this recursive call happens - and if it is CDATA, then you need to add the node value to your result array directly, instead of the recursive call.

Comment: The other alternative would be to handle that at the start of the function, check if the node type is CDATA there, if so return the node value directly. `if($root->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) { return $root->nodeValue; }`

Comment: @CBroe but #cdata-section not remove. the result is ["lastmod"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["#cdata-section"]=>
          string(25) "2022-02-02T20:24:34+07:00"
        } . and i am solve with add params to loadXML($xml,LIBXML_NOCDATA)

Comment: You did not say you wanted it removed, you said you needed to get access to the value ... `if($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) { $result = $child->nodeValue; continue; }` at the beginning of the foreach loop seems to do the trick, at least if the element contains nothing but a single CDATA section. (If there can be more of them, or other types of sibling nodes, then it would need more modification still.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the generic conversion into an array structure does not support that `lastmod` contains 3 nodes. The CDATA-Section is surrounded by two text nodes containing the white spaces. You might get around this specific problem by setting the `DOMDocument::$preserveWhiteSpace` property to `false`.

However I would suggest directly reading the DOM with Xpath expressions.

```php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>https://www.blablal.id/news/sitemap.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>
      <![CDATA[ 2022-02-02T12:21:02+07:00 ]]>
    </lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register a prefix for the used default namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace(
    'map', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
);

$sitemaps = [];
// iterate the sitemap element nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//map:sitemap') as $sitemap) {
    $sitemaps[] = [
         // read text content of specific child nodes
        'loc' => trim($xpath->evaluate('string(map:loc)', $sitemap)),
        'lastmod' => trim($xpath->evaluate('string(map:lastmod)', $sitemap))
    ];
}

var_dump($sitemaps);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["loc"]=>
    string(39) "https://www.blablal.id/news/sitemap.xml"
    ["lastmod"]=>
    string(25) "2022-02-02T12:21:02+07:00"
  }
}
```